# How to get collection with Trashed Laravel Resource

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

I have a problem I try to get list of posts with trashed posts through Resource API. Code example here

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $perPage = (int) $request->get('per_page');
    if ($perPage < 1 or $perPage > 1000) {
        $perPage = config('database.paginate');
    }
    $clubId = (int)$request->get('club');
    $query = Playground::query();
    if ($clubId) {
        $query = $query->where('club_id', $clubId);
    }
    return PlaygroundResource::collection($query->paginate($perPage));
}
```

I cant add `->withTrashed()` method in collection, So how can i get all posts???

UPD::
Playground Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'slug',
    'name',
    'club_id',
    'links',
    'playground_types',
    'services',
    'equipments',
    'surfaces',
    'sports',
    'type',
    'description'
];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Comment: Playground model show @Serufim

Comment: Have you tried putting the `->withTrashed()` behind the `$query`? For example right after you define it? `$query = Playground::query();
$query->withTrashed();`

Comment: @Teun thanks very much

Comment: @Teun Add as an answer so it can be marked as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `->withTrashed()` behind the `$query`? For example right after you define it?

```
$query = Playground::query(); 
$query->withTrashed();
```